# Extracting a part of an email using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have an email address like this flavius.david@yahoo.com.
I want to extract "david". I've had tried this

```
`"m[^([^.]*)-([^+]*)\@.*$];"`  
print " $&\n";
```

But, resulte is only "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/[^.]+(?=@)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP2bM1/1)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what else you're doing, but I would write something like

```
my @names = $email =~ /\w+/g;
my $sname = $names[1];
```

Comment: could not get shorter and matches all parts... i like it :)

Answer (score 0):

if you need both parts, your original regex was close, but should read:

```
^([^.]*)\.([^@]*)@.*$
```

[RegEx Playground](https://regex101.com/r/iI7bA9/1)

Comment: I've had tried this, but is not working. See the resulte on  http://rubular.com/r/GyMBHn6zhT

Comment: it works there too... the complete match is always the full result, you must access the match groups... group 1 is first part before the . and group 2 is the second name... look in the match groups box or try the regex link, i just fix it, had a wrong link there